# A view ALL option in jqgrid is resulting in NaNs for row numbers and totals

Tags: jqgrid

I added "ALL" to my RowList.

Then on the backend I changed my LIMIT to the total count of the record result if ALL is detected. It kinda works.  It shows all the records like I want it.  But all the row numbers show NaN as well as the paging and totals at the bottom.  If I look at the data in the XML nothing looks wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jqGrid don't support words like "ALL" in the `rowList`. So you have to include some large enough value like 10000 in the `rowList` array. What you do can do is to *rename* the text in the corresponding select to another word like `ALL`. For example if you have

```js
$('#grid').jqGrid({
    ...
    pager: '#pager',
    rowList: [10, 20, 50, 10000],
    rowNum: 10
});
```

you can use the following statement

```js
$("#pager option[value=10000]").text('All');
```

to rename the text `10000` (but not the corresponding value) to 'All':

[image]

In the case you will have no problem with the column which displays row numbers.

Comment: Works beautifully.  Exactly what I wanted.  Thanks for the quick response.